# How to automatically logout when user idle time is 5 mins in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to automatically

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.RemoveAll();
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
```

when user idle time is 5 mins in MVC4 project?

Comment: 5 minutes is really f'in short.

Comment: You also need to define what is "idle"? No request at all for five minutes?

Comment: @AdrianGodong yeah, No request at all for five minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your definition of idle, looks like you can do it by using both [`SlidingExpiration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration.aspx) and [`Timeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.timeout.aspx) property of the `FormsAuthentication` class.

Set Timeout to 5 minutes and SlidingExpiration to true and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this at the IIS level.

In IIS you can set the session-timeout at any time you want.

This article on technet explains you how to do that:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820(v=ws.10).aspx

Note: the user will only be redirected to the login-page once he takes another action (when the session has ended)

Answer (score -2):

if you want that logged in content should also be hidden after 5 min, then you can combine Kenneths answer with little javascript on each page.

```
setTimeout(function () { 
    // iis will handle the rest.
    location.reload(); 
}, 300000);
```

Comment: If you do that, it must be server-initiated. Also, users will not like this with form input.

Comment: whats that "it" that has to be server-initiated? Forms authentication itself will logout on reload and redirect to loginurl (if needed) and preserve returnulr. And what exactly users don't like? That when they are idle. their page is automatically logged out? What about personal data? Do you want that any other person sees your page where you left off and forgot to log out?

Comment: By "it" I mean the server logoff. A page shouldn't just reload after a set timeout, because as I said users will lose input. It could for example poll the server whether the user is still logged in, and if not, put a "Please Login Again" overlay on the page.